# Why does the Selection Principle imply the Ordering Principle?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Jech's *Axiom of Choice* book, exercise 4.12 is that the Selection Principle (for all $\mathcal{F}$ there is a function $f: \mathcal{F} \rightarrow V$ such that $|X| \ge 2 \rightarrow \emptyset \subsetneq f(X) \subsetneq X$) is equivalent to K(1) (every set can be injected into $\mathcal{P}(Ord)$). He remarks, "Consequently, the Selection Principle implies the Ordering Principle [every partial order can be extended to a total order]." This isn't obvious to me.

My guess is the intended proof is something like this: "Let $(P, \le)$ be a partial order. We may assume $P=\mathcal{P}(\alpha),$ for some ordinal $\alpha.$ There is some canonical way to strictly extend the ordering. By transfinite iteration, there is a canonical total extension of the ordering." I can't tell what this canonical way to extend $(P,\le)$ is. My first guess was to find the minimal $\beta<\alpha$ such that two incomparable elements differ at $\beta,$ and for all pairs $p \perp q,$ where $\beta \in q \setminus p,$ declare $p<q.$ Unfortunately, this can create a cycle in the order. I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Do you mean Problem 4.12?

Comment: Yes, I'll fix it.

Comment: Let me find one reference, and then I'll post my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misreading things.

The ordering principle states "Every set can be linearly ordered". The order *extension* principle states "every partial order can be extended to a linear order".

If every set can be injectively mapped into $\mathcal P(\alpha)$ for some ordinal $\alpha$, then it will inherit the linear ordering definable on $\mathcal P(\alpha)$.

Interestingly enough, I cannot find any work separating Kinna–Wagner's Selection Principle (Or $\sf KW$ or $\sf KWP_1$ as it is sometimes denoted) from the Order Extension Principle. Either the non-implication is known, or the question is still open, as indicated by the diagrams in Herrlich's "Axiom of Choice" book.

Comment: Oh. Example 2.32 is confusingly phrased then. I can't believe I banged my head against this for the last few hours.

Comment: *"We shall show that the Prime Ideal Theorem implies that every set can be linearly ordered. Actually, we get a stronger theorem. [...]"*

Comment: I don't think it's unreasonable to expect that Jech explicitly state which theorem "ordering principle" is referring to.

Comment: Well. Mistakes do happen. Let's talk after you've written your first "accessible book" on a topic...

Comment: @ElliotGlazer Not to pile on, but it's also implicit in the proof and statement of thm 4.7